# Can we include a procedure (let's say check wind ) in both the setup and go procedure of NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am building a model for dispersion of pollutants in air for which I want to import wind velocity information stored in a .csv file. I was wondering if the procedure to check wind from at each tick can also be included in the setup procedure to assign wind velocity values at tick 0 ? I am not sure if code is needed for this question but please let me know if at all it is needed .

Comment: I answered this because you are new and I thought an example might help you. But this is the sort of thing that you will learn more by simply trying to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with this. For example, I routinely do this for such things as colouring patches by some value that changes - you want the colouring to apply at all times. In that case, the code would look something like:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  [ bunch of stuff to initialise the world ]
  colour-patches
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  [ bunch of stuff to make changes to the worl ]
  colour-patches
  tick
end

to colour-patches
  [ stuff to do the colouring ]
end
```